# Sencha touch build error - iPhone Developer: no identity found

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am trying to build sencha touch app using my mac. Earlier it was working fine. But now i can build the app but when i try to install it in to itunes am getting an error "Itunes Sync installation failed". Then i googled some and find out my ios development certificate is expired so i create a new certificate and profile. Now when i try to build it with sencha app build native command am getting following error

[ERR] failed running native packager
[ERR] Copy operation failed src=/Users/abyv/Documents/crmappbugfix/build/authorit/native/WinREOMobileCRM.app/webapp/resources/icons/iTunesArtwork dst=/Users/abyv/Documents/crmappbugfix/build/authorit/native/WinREOMobileCRM.app/iTunesArtwork
iPhone Developer: no identity found

I googled alot for this.. couldn't find any solution plz help me to solve this issue..thanks in advance

this is the packager.json file

```
{
    /**
     * @cfg  applicationName
     * @required
     * This is the name of your application, which is displayed on the device when the app is installed. On IOS, this should match
     * the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationName":"WinREOMobileCRM",

    /**
     * @cfg  applicationId
     * This is the name namespace for your application. On IOS, this should match the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationId":"LL44QWX773.in.amt.winreomobilecrm",

    /**
     * @cfg  bundleSeedId
     * A ten character string which stands before aplication ID in Apple Provisioning Portal
     */
    "bundleSeedId":"LL44QWX773",

    /**
     * @cfg  versionString
     * @required
     * This is the version of your application.
     */
    "versionString":"1.0",

    /**
     * @cfg  versionCode
     * @required
     * This is the integer version code of your application, or you can refer to it as a build number. Used only for Android builds.
     */
    "versionCode":"1",

    /**
     * @cfg  icon
     * For iOS, please refer to their documentation about icon sizes:
     * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html
     *
     * For Android, please refer to the Google Launcher icons guide:
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html
     * iOS uses 57, 72, 114 and 144; Android uses 36, 48 and 72; if you package for Android you can ignore iOS icons and vice verca
     */
    "icon": {
        "36":"resources/icons/Icon_Android36.png",
        "48":"resources/icons/Icon_Android48.png",
        "57":"resources/icons/Icon.png",
        "72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
        "114":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png",
        "144":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png"
    },

    /**
     * @cfg  inputPath
     * @required
     * This is location of your Sencha Touch 2 application, relative to this configuration file.
     */
    "inputPath":"./",

    /**
     * @cfg  outputPath
     * @required
     * This is where the built application file with be saved. Make sure that output path is not in your input path, you may get into endless recursive copying
     */
    "outputPath":"../build/",

    /**
     * @cfg  configuration
     * @required
     * This is configuration for your application. `Debug` should always be used unless you are submitting your app to an online
     * store - in which case `Release` should be specified.
     */
    "configuration":"Debug",

    /**
     * @cfg  platform
     * @required
     * This is the platform where you will be running your application. Available options are:
     *  - iOSSimulator
     *  - iOS
     *  - Android
     *  - AndroidEmulator
     */
    "platform":"iOS",

    /**
     * @cfg  deviceType
     * @required
     * This is device type that your application will be running on.
     *
     * If you are developing for Android, this is not necessary.
     *
     * Available options are:
     *  - iPhone
     *  - iPad
     *  - Universal
     */
    "deviceType":"Universal",

    /**
     * @cfg  certificatePath
     * This is the location of your certificate.
     * This is required when you are developing for Android or you are developing on Windows.
     */
    "certificatePath":"/Users/abyv/Documents/certnew/ios_development.cer",

    /**
     * @cfg  certificateAlias
     * This is the name of your certificate.
     *
     * IF you do not specify this on OSX, we will try and automatically find the certificate for you using the applicationId.
     *
     * This can be just a simple matcher. For example, if your certificate name is "iPhone Developer: Robert Dougan (ABCDEFGHIJ)", you
     * can just put "iPhone Developer".
     *
     * When using a certificatePath on Windows, you do not need to specify this.
     */
    "certificateAlias":"iPhone Developer",
    /**
     * @cfg  certificatePassword
     * The password which was specified during certificate export
     */
    "certificatePassword":"",
    /**
     * @cfg  provisionProfile
     * The path to the provision profile (APP_NAME.mobileprovision) which you can create and then download from Apple's provisioning portal
     */
    "provisionProfile":"/Users/abyv/Documents/certnew/WinREOMobileCRMProfile.mobileprovision",
    /**
     * @cfg  notificationConfiguration
     * Notification configuration for push notifications, can be "debug", "release" or empty if you don't use push notifications in your project.
     */
    "notificationConfiguration":"",
    /**
     * @cfg  sdkPath
     * This is the path to the Android SDK, if you are developing an Android application.
     */
    "sdkPath":"/path/to/android-sdk",

    /**
     * @cfg  androidAPILevel
     * This is android API level, the version of Android SDK to use, you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.
     * Be sure to install corresponding platform API in android SDK manager (android_sdk/tools/android)
     */
    "androidAPILevel":"8",

        /**
     * @cfg {Array[String]} permissions
     * Array of permissions that is used by an application (Android only) 
     * Full list of permissions for Android application can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
     */
    "permissions":[
            "INTERNET",
            "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
            "CAMERA",
            "VIBRATE",
            "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
            "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
            "CALL_PHONE"
        ],

    /**
     * @cfg {Array[String]} orientations
     * @required
     * This is orientations that this application can run.
     */
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",

        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your provisioning profile has not expired. Also, check whether the private key is imported to the keychain. This issue is something to do with more of iOS provisioning profile settings.

Comment: how can i import my provisioning profile to keychain?.. i just double click it. but i couldn't find it my keychain

am also getting this error
Failed to execute system command while signing application with error 256
Failed to package application

Comment: I have managed to solve this issue. problem with my provisioning profile..i have build another profile and give it id to pacakager.json 

     "applicationId":"LL44QWX773.*",
     "bundleSeedId":"LL44QWX773.*",

there are two type of provisional profile i build a provisional profile with xcode app id ..now everything is working fine..thanks for Geeniewanted comment